# Oracle script stopped working silently without any exceptions

Tags: oracle

I have an Oracle script that takes some time to execute (merge/update of millions of rows), it is executed via sqlplus and output is redirected to log file. The execution of the script is not consistant, sometimes it ran successfully in 50' which was good enough for us, but sometimes the script never stopped, and no exceptions were logged, the log file remained empty and sqlplus seemed stucked. I watched after the running queries in Oracle, they suddenly had disapeared (after approx. 1 hour) like if someone automatically killed the transaction or the process internly. No rows were updated.
I'm not Oracle DBA so i have no idea what to check to understand what happened there...

I have illustrated my question with an example using a merge instruction but encountered the problem on many other scripts (massive inserts for example).
The common point is when the script requires massive Oracle ressources, I could change the script and do a more optimized version of this massive update but i am really curious to understand what exactly happen here and why i have no information at all in this specific case.
I have checked Windows event log and found nothing.
I don't know where to search in Oracle to understand what happened. I'm sure there must have some internal logs but my knowledge in Oracle administration is too limited and i need help on that point.

```
SET TIMING ON
SET SERVEROUTPUT ON SIZE unlimited
SET FEEDBACK OFF

DECLARE
    PROCEDURE SYMAG_MERGE_CUST_LASTACT 
    IS
        start_time number:= DBMS_UTILITY.get_time; 
        alter_time number; 
        merge_time number; 
        commit_time number; 
        end_time number;
    BEGIN

    -- Session settings 
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET skip_unusable_indexes = true';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS nologging';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION ENABLE PARALLEL DML';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION FORCE PARALLEL DML';

    alter_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('= Alter1: '||to_char((alter_time-start_time)/100)||'s ');

    MERGE /*+ first_rows parallel(C,8) parallel(SRC,8) */ INTO CUSTOMERS C
    USING (SELECT CST_CODE FROM CUSTOMERS WHERE STA_CODE <> 0) SRC ON (C.CST_CODE = SRC.CST_CODE)
    WHEN MATCHED THEN UPDATE SET CST_DATELASTACT = sysdate;

    merge_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('= Merge: '||to_char((merge_time-alter_time)/100)||'s ');

    -- Commit 
    COMMIT;
    commit_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('= Commit: '||to_char((commit_time-merge_time)/100)||'s ');

    -- Session settings restore
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER SESSION SET skip_unusable_indexes = false';
    EXECUTE IMMEDIATE 'ALTER TABLE CUSTOMERS logging';

    end_time := DBMS_UTILITY.get_time;
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('= Alter2: '||to_char((end_time-commit_time)/100)||'s ');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('----------------------------------------------------------');
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('= Total time: '||to_char((end_time-start_time)/100)||'s ');

EXCEPTION   
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('= Exception : ' || SQLCODE || ' - ' || SQLERRM);
        Rollback;
        DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('= Rollback');
END;

BEGIN
    DBMS_OUTPUT.PUT_LINE('=== Start of script step 3-4(v2)');
    SYMAG_MERGE_CUST_LASTACT();
END;
/

EXIT;
```

I expect the script to stop everytime it is executed and display at least an Oracle exception or understand what happened in Oracle to prevent the script from being stucked without any error logged.

Edit : 
When checking the alert_.log, I only have these logs at script's execution time :

```
**Fatal NI connect error 12170.**

VERSION INFORMATION:
    TNS for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
    Oracle Bequeath NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
    TCP/IP NT Protocol Adapter for Linux: Version 12.1.0.2.0 - Production
Time: 21-AUG-2019 17:28:57
Tracing not turned on.
Tns error struct:
    ns main err code: 12535

TNS-12535: TNS:operation timed out
    ns secondary err code: 12560
    nt main err code: 505

TNS-00505: Operation timed out
    nt secondary err code: 110
    nt OS err code: 0
Client address: (ADDRESS=(PROTOCOL=tcp)(HOST=10.126.84.228)(PORT=10686))
Wed Aug 21 17:45:36 2019
```

Comment: [1] It is virtually impossible to resolve your problem(s) without more information. See [Locating and Configuring Enterprise Manager Log Files](https://docs.oracle.com/cd/B14117_01/em.101/b12013/logging.htm) and then update your question with the relevant log data. [2] Also see [Oracle Enterprise Manager - Where do I find the error logs?](https://dba.stackexchange.com/questions/62540/oracle-enterprise-manager-where-do-i-find-the-error-logs). [3] I think your question might be more appropriate for [Database Administrators Stack Exchange](https://dba.stackexchange.com/).

Comment: One of the few reasons why an Oracle job aborts without any message is because of an ORA-600 or ORA-7445 error, where the background process suddenly dies.  When that happens, there should be an entry in the alert log.  Check for a file named something like alert_DBNAME.log, in the directory `select value from v$diag_info where name = 'Diag Trace';`  Hopefully that file has more details about the error.  Or if you think something else is killing the process or shell script, you might want to run the code through DBMS_SCHEDULER.

Comment: I've edited my post with log traces (indicating maybe an issue with the oracle listener configuration). I still don't understand why Oracle raised some exceptions (whatever they might be) and none of them are catched in my script, there might be something wrong but I have no clue about what it can be.